# Change transparency of PNG images

Tags: libpng

I want to change transparency of PNG images. I used libPNG to accomplish this, but unable to change only transparency of background. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean with that ? change into what ?

Comment: change background of image to transparent using libpng.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware PNG doesn't really store any background/foreground.
You can use the Imagemagick's `convert` to achieve similar results. For example to remove all the white

```
convert -transparent white input.png output.png
```

If you want to do more complicated things and define a background I suggest you use a visual tool like GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

You can set one color to be transparent. If I remember right than it is called alpha channel an can be set via "libpng". Actually, it is a fourth pixel of each and every RGB pixel. Any tool like Adobe Photoshop, GIMP or Corel Graphics is, of course, able to assist appropriately.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Consider posting this as a comment instead of an answer. After gaining certain number of reputation points you will be able to post comments to other questions/answer.